# How do I set the "type" of a React Fiber?

Tags: reactjs, react-fiber

I have a custom React Fiber Reconciler, which I create using the default export from the `react-reconciler` package.
In a ReactDOM Component, I execute

```js
this.mountNode = CustomRenderer.createContainer(this.stage)
CustomRenderer.updateContainer(
  <SomeContextProvider>{children}<SomeContextProvider/>,
  this.mountNode,
  this
)
```

However, when I open the React devtools, I get

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null  in the getDataFiber method here:
    case HostComponent:
        nodeType = 'Native';
        name = fiber.type;

        // TODO (bvaughn) we plan to remove this prefix anyway.
        // We can cut this special case out when it's gone.
        name = name.replace('topsecret-', ''); /////////// Error here on this line
```

This appears to be because `fiber.type` is null.
Searching around, i see people passing a type as the second argument to their renderer's createContainer, but doing so gives me a weird and seemingly unrelated error of

```js
Uncaught TypeError: scheduleDeferredCallback is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: cancelDeferredCallback is not a function
```

, so this probably isn't the right thing to do.

The Host config is pretty long, so here it is in a gist: https://gist.github.com/arilotter/d34c684da13a4825285ddfe021ec4be3

And here's my `package.json`:
https://gist.github.com/arilotter/fd53712900f726a46c1d9a6ceeaf151c

**Where can I specify the `type` for my container, so the devtools work?**

Comment: May be name = name && name.replace('topsecret-', '');

Comment: @Think-Twice the error is in React code, not in my code :(

Comment: Can you show the CustomRender hostConfig

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri added to the post

Comment: Can you show `package.json`?

Comment: @Alex added to the post as well

Comment: If you can provide a codesandbox or something, I think it will be useful and easier for someone to help you out